# How to Foley goat or sheep footsteps

Tags: foley, footsteps, animals

I'm trying to foley some mountain goat jumping on a rock and walking.
I already found a [perfect reference in a documentary](https://youtu.be/NcRifDitRnU?t=1310) (you can listen to those footsteps for awhile). Another example can be found in the [pig sequence](https://youtu.be/xNkLfYItKeQ?t=9) from the film Black Widow.

I made some tests in the filed with different sizes of small carton boxes, first empty, then stuffed with different amounts of tissues, but i don't get a satisfying result, and half coconut would have too much resonance, and too low pitch. Any advise would be very welcome.

Comment: I don't have a definite solution for you but some things to bear in mind are: the rocks sliding around are louder than the hooves. Hooves are quite dense - you might get a better result if you filled small plastic containers with ice, wax, or something else with a similar density. I know this is a bit gross but have you considered getting some pigs feet from your local butcher? Another thing to consider is the direction and weight that you're using and the surface you're hitting them on - does it match what you're seeing on the screen?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i didn't thought about ice and wax, this is a very good idea! I will try this out and post later some results just for logging, in case someone else is wonderning the same thing in the future.